# Eclipse JFace Tree - Empty column names for a Tree table

Tags: java, eclipse, treeview, jface

I want to create a tree table in Java using org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TableViewer. In my view class, which extends org.eclipse.ui.part.ViewPart, in overriden method doCreatePartControl(), I have this:

```
    parent.setLayout(new GridLayout());
    Composite composite = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
    composite.setLayout(new GridLayout());
    composite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));      
    this.headers = Arrays.asList("Column 1", "Column 2"); //headers is an ArrayList<String>

    this.sashForm = new SashForm(composite, SWT.NONE | SWT.VERTICAL);
    this.sashForm.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
    Composite myComposite = new Composite(this.sashForm, SWT.NONE);     
    myComposite .setLayout(new GridLayout());
    myComposite .setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));              
    this.myTree = new MyTree(myComposite,
                                         SWT.BORDER | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL,
                                         this, this.headers);
```

The class MyTree extends org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree, and it's constructor is:

```
public AdaptersTree(Composite parent, int style,  IViewPart view, List<String> columns)
{
    super(parent, style);
    setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
    this.viewPart = view;
  
    this.treeViewer = new TreeViewer(this, SWT.MULTI | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
    this.treeViewer.setContentProvider(new MyTreeContentProvider());
   
    this.headers = columns;
    
    setHeaderVisible(true);
    setLinesVisible(true);

    for (String header : this.headers) // create columns names
    {
        TreeViewerColumn viewerColumn = new TreeViewerColumn(treeViewer, SWT.NONE);
        viewerColumn.getColumn().setWidth(150);
        viewerColumn.getColumn().setText(header);
        viewerColumn.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider());
    }
    
    GridLayoutFactory.fillDefaults().generateLayout(this);

}
```

The class MyTreeContentProvider is a sample class which implements the interface org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ITreeContentProvider:

```
class MyTreeContentProvider implements ITreeContentProvider {
@Override
public boolean hasChildren(Object element) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public Object getParent(Object element) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public Object[] getElements(Object inputElement) { // not important now
    if (input instanceof ITreeItem[]) {
        
    }
    return new ArrayList<Object>();
}

@Override
public Object[] getChildren(Object parentElement) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void dispose()
{      
}

@Override
public void inputChanged(Viewer viewer, Object oldInput, Object newInput)
{   
}
```

In this moment, I want to have an empty table. But with this implementation, the view is displayed, but the headers ("Column 1" and "Column 2") are not.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is the `TreeViewer` constructor you are using:

```
this.treeViewer = new TreeViewer(this, SWT.MULTI | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
```

This constructor creates a new `Tree` internally. Since you have already created the tree you should be using:

```
this.treeViewer = new TreeViewer(this);
```

Also note that the `GridLayoutFactory` call at the end is not necessary.

Comment: Yes, I removed the GridLayoutFactory and it was OK. I had to change the approach, because I needed to use an internal TreeContentProvider.